# What is the origin of phrase "for fun and profit"?

Tags: etymology, phrases

Sounds like something a snake oil salesman on the wild west could come up with. Can the origins be traced?

**Edit:**

In a transcript of a state trial from 1798:

> What did you give it him for? Did he make use of it? Was it to protect his copper from being changed that you did it? — He was very officious to make things in a light easy way without much trouble, to make nis bread light. But I did it *more in fun than profit*.

This is clearly not the same phrase, but it seems to be more than an accidental use of those two words togather.

Comment: The origins are clearly very old, just wanted to note, that this got famous in recent computer culture through the article "[Smashing the Stack for Fun and Profit](http://phrack.org/issues/49/14.html)" in Phrack Magazine #49 from 1996.

Comment: @bfncs that's a pretty tenuous claim without evidence to back it up.  There were several computer-related "for fun and profit" books published in the 1980s and early 1990s, and even more non-computer-related "for fun and profit" books published since the early 20th century.  If the phrase was already famous in general culture as a component of the titles of "how-to" manuals, there would have been no need for a separate rise to fame *in* computer culture.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I don't know about the origins, but it is definitely not a recent expression. 
As the following examples found with Google Books indicate, the expression is used since the 19th century at least:

> [Pamphlets, Religious: Miscellaneous](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=bwYdAQAAMAAJ&pg=RA2-PA60&dq=%22for%20fun%20and%20profit%22&hl=en&ei=zhnNTa3WHtGbhQfgwsWUDQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=3&ved=0CDYQ6AEwAg)
>   (**1847)**
>
> It matters not if you call it a
>   "fish pond" *for fun and profit*„or a
>   five cent chance to get a quilt at a
>   draw or a raffle given by a Ladies'
>   Aid Society of Church, or the profits
>   on editing a newspaper for one day, or
>   running a railroad

-

> [The American Angler](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=pnQYAQAAIAAJ&q=%22for%20fun%20and%20profit%22&dq=%22for%20fun%20and%20profit%22&hl=en&ei=zhnNTa3WHtGbhQfgwsWUDQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=4&ved=0CDoQ6AEwAw) (**1897**)
>
> I am now fixing up some trout ponds, a
>   pet scheme of mine, in which I shall
>   propagate trout *for fun and profit*.
>   The law here is, that no one can sell
>   trout in market unless from private
>   ponds, and I shall of course be in the
>   game.

Comment: what's the association with fish ponds, 50yrs apart

Answer (score 12):

I found the phrase back to 1833 ([check](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=A1ctAAAAMAAJ&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false)) in an English translation of a book by the French novelist [Charles Paul de Kock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_Paul_de_Kock) called [*The Modern Cymon*](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=A1ctAAAAMAAJ&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q=fun%20and%20profit&f=false). Here, three characters have hatched a plan to simulate a two-headed man they hope others will pay to see:

[image: "fun and profit" clip from Google Books]

Answer (score 3):

It seems a rough translation of Horace, Ars Poetica, "Prodesse et delectare".

Comment: Interesting.  Could you please expand upon this a little.  It would make the answer more credible.

Comment: From DE Wikipedia (via Google Translate): "Prodesse et delectare ( Latin, "avail and enjoy ") is a motto of literature , especially in the 18th century./This should emphasize the Enlightenment aspect of the literature: books should be both entertaining and instructive for the reader. A typical example of such works are fables . / The saying derives from the Ars Poetica..." See examples of "profit and entertainment" like 1825 https://books.google.com/books?id=0XhAAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA1&dq="profit+and+entertainment" , 1745 https://books.google.com/books?id=-HBIAAAAYAAJ&q="profit+and+entertainment" ,etc

Comment: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prodesse_et_delectare

Comment: The phrase "for fun and profit" definitely implies _monetary profit_ specifically. "Prodesse et delectare" is a motto expressing the idea that literature should both instruct and entertain (where "instruction" here primarily means moral instruction/edification). I don't think it's really related to "for fun and profit" at all. "For fun and profit" suggests the idea of turning a hobby one engages in for personal pleasure into a (probably secondary) source of monetary income.