# What's the opposite of "pro bono"?

Tags: phrase-requests, vocabulary, antonyms, latin

The Latin *[pro bono](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pro_bono)* is used to describe performance of (often professional or specialized) services for free or for reduced compensation.  Is there a corresponding (hopefully Latin, perhaps *pro-SOMETHING*) phrase for performance of services for pay (i.e., normal/conventional compensation)?

I perused Wikipedia's [list of Latin "P" phrases](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Latin_phrases_(P)) and didn't find anything satisfactory. *Pro rata* is perhaps plausible (in the sense of pay-as-you-go), but I don't think I have seen it used in this sense. I suppose the phrase I seek describes the "normal" case, so it doesn't often need a clarifying phrase (in contrast to the "abnormal" case described by *pro bono*).

I could certainly use a literal English phrase like "for money" or "for a fee" (e.g., as [suggested here](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20130912143932AA345Kn)). 
However, that doesn't seem as elegant (as *pro bono* is somewhat more elegant and more specific than "for free"). I'm also interested in this as describing a situation: analogous to *pro bono* describing the arrangement of services being provided at reduced fee, this term explicitly identifies the arrangement as services being performed at the conventional rate.

Such a phrase could also be used in a somewhat jocular or droll way; for example, a student asking for help with an implicit *pro bono* sense:

> Student A: Would you help me with my homework?
>   Student B: I would be willing to help ***pro [appropriate compensation]***...

Perhaps that, itself, works in this usage... :)

Comment: @mplungjan Pro malo: "for an apple"

Comment: Remunerated / for a consideration/fee.. _Not_ pro fessionally.

Comment: If you can't easily find such a word, what makes you think your readers/listeners/student-A would understand it? Just speak clear English.

Comment: @AndrewLeach: *Pro mālo* would mean "for an apple", which would make sense in Dutch, where the expression *voor een appel en een ei* ("for an apple and an egg") means "for very little money". *Pro mălo* would mean "in exchange for something bad, for disaster".

Comment: The reason why "pro bono" sounds better is that doesn't mean (strictly) "for free": it means "for good", for the good, for the public good, i.e. to be beneficial/charitable/virtuous.

Comment: Do you actually want a Latin phrase? If so, I think you've come to the wrong site.

Comment: Seems the downvoters of my suggestions did not notice the jocular/droll part.

Comment: Literally "for hire" --> "I'm available for hire".

Comment: @MattЭллен: [Latin.SE](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/75409/latin-language) is still in Area51; do you have another suggestion? Seemed on-topic enough and more response than I expected.

Comment: @ChrisW: I agree with your specificity on the term. I intended a looser meaning of *pro bono*; is lacking the "public good" connotation legitimate usage? Or is such usage a colloquial misnomer?

Comment: @hoc_age Typically "pro bono" is work which a lawyer does on the cheap, in the interest of public justice, e.g. when they act as [public defender](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_defender). "pro bono" literally (in Latin) means "for good" so I can't see it as having any other (looser) meaning. If you want to talk about money perhaps say [ex gratia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ex_gratia).

Comment: FYI [an irrelevant aside](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gratis_versus_libre#.22Free_beer.22_vs_.22free_speech.22_distinction) on the topic of the word "free" in English.

Comment: "Pre U2"? #cultural-reference

Comment: Amateur Bono. Before he was paid to perform for U2.

Comment: @Khanzor See you got there before me... Well played!

Comment: @ColinBanbury Wouldn't the opposite of "pro Bono" be "pro bono Bono"? This could get tricky.

Comment: There's "for profit", of course, but it might put you in the vicinity of ["for fun and profit"](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/25205/77982), and you're looking for a latin phrase anyway.

Comment: @ChrisW: What, then, is the conventional opposite of *ex gratia*? The same as in your answer?

Comment: gratia means [grace or favour](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=gratia&la=la#lexicon) i.e. perhaps it means a gift, which you give without creating an obligation on the other party to repay you (and, in law, without admitting that what you give is a repayment of a debt, which would admit that you have a debt, which would put further obligation on you if the amount given weren't enough to compensate the such-acknowledged debt). The opposite of [ex gratia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ex_gratia) is to say that there's a [quid pro quo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quid_pro_quo).

Comment: I think the reason we don't have a well-known phrase like this is because working for hire is the normal arrangement. _pro bono_ is used to describe an exception to the rule. We don't need to say anything to describe the default case. _pro bono_ is mostly used to refer to lawyers, and they normally get paid handsomely.

Comment: Related: [The opposite of “free” in phrases](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/445811/).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So, to be clear, you're looking for a way to say "for money" in Latin: using a "pro" construct that's not in the list of phrases that are commonly used in English.

Perhaps "pro denario" (singular) or "pro denariis" (plural) -- where 'denarius' is Roman currency -- or "pro argento" (meaning silver), or "pro pecunia" (money), or "pro salario" or "pro honorario".

---

If you want to say that you're doing it in exchange for something (usually money), you can say that you expect a "[quid pro quo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quid_pro_quo)", which *is* a well-known Latin expression.

Comment: What happened to the lively commentary here? Many thanks; this answer accepted on the technicality that this identified the sense I was seeking *in this case*; in addition to *quid pro quo* from comments elsewhere. I wish I could also accept @SvenYargs [excellent answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/200481/78185), which will undoubtedly be enshrined as the popular answer (and more correct in the absolute sense). Upvotes all around and thanks.

Answer (score 18):

As *Black's Law Dictionary* (1968) points out, *pro bono* is short for "*pro bono publico*":

> **PRO BONO PUBLICO.** For the public good; for the welfare of the whole.

The underlying notion is that the task or decision is undertaken or made in order to serve the society or the nation as a whole. That being the case, you might argue that a counterpoint in the law is offered by the expression "*pro interesse suo*":

> **PRO INTERESSE SUO.** According to his interest; to the extent of his interest. Thus a third party may be allowed to intervene in a suit *pro interesse suo*.

But this represents an opposition to *pro bono publico* only in the sense that self-interest and public interest are seen as being in conflict. Philosophically, people tend to a have a high standard for altruism, insisting that it not entail material advantage to the altruist if it is to qualify as altruistic. But in practical terms, even deeply self-interested parties may benefit from policies and actions that advance the public good—and conversely, selfish actions sometimes serve the general welfare.

---

The logical opposite of *pro bono publico* is *contra bono publico*—but this phrase yields very few matches in a Google Books search. One instance where it does appear is in "['Moral Obligation' and 'Secret Preferences' in Bankruptcy Composition](http://books.google.com/books?id=WDctAQAAIAAJ&q=%22contra+bono+publico%22&dq=%22contra+bono+publico%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=kHo1VO_GFcmuoQSQ6oLoCQ&ved=0CFQQ6AEwBzgK)," in *American Bankruptcy Review* (March 1937), quoting a New York appellate court's decision in *Posner v. Rosenbaum* (1934) [combined snippets]:

> "The final defense of *contra bono publico* is, likewise, entitled to little credence .... because plaintiffs had not agreed to do anything which would retard the discharge of the bankrupt, but rather aided payment to the other creditors and hastened the discharge of the bankrupt."

*Black's Law Dictionary* does not have an entry for *contra bono publico*, though it does have one for *contra bonos mores* ("against good morals").

Comment: Why *pro interesse*? I do not believe that is correct syntactically?

Comment: I can't explain why that wording was used—but _that_ it was used is clear from a Google Books search. For example, from _[Reports of Sir Edward Coke](http://books.google.com/books?id=77I3AQAAMAAJ&pg=PA66&dq=%22pro+interesse%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=63I1VNbtKYXsoASkj4HICQ&ved=0CDgQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=%22pro%20interesse%22&f=false)_ (1656): "That Wiskard, who is a meer stranger to the Suit, and who comes in Pro interesse suo in the said Rectory, pleads matter meerly determinable at the Common Law, scil. Letters Patents, Feeffment, and Lease for years: ..."

Comment: @Cerberus "[interesse](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/interesse#Latin)" is the "present active infinitive of [intersum](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/intersum#Latin)", therefore it's not a noun with an [ablative case](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ablative_(Latin)): "for between-being (e.g. money-making) of oneself"

Comment: I appreciate your answer as the literal antithesis of public good, and is probably the Correct Answer to the Question, but my question and usage was more implicitly colloquial (and, strictly speaking, largely incorrect.) Thank you for the answer *and* the schooling.

Comment: @Cerberus et al; slightly OT PSA: I hope you all have upvoted the [Latin-language](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/75409/latin-language) site!

Comment: @ChrisW: "Therefore it's not a noun with an ablative case"? I'm not sure what you mean, but you cannot use an infinitive after a preposition: you'd have to use a gerund, but there is no gerund of *esse*, so it is not possible. Further, *pro* in this case probably means *in defence of*, which you cannot use with your own interests; it would probably have to be a dative of purpose. Lastly, only the third person *interest* normally means "be of interest"; normally the verb means "be between, be among, be present at", and the sense "be of interest" requires special conditions.

Comment: So, in other words, your suggestion **pro interesse suo* is not possible. I understand that this phrase was coined by you but by a certain lawyer, but I have to say it makes a classicist cringe.

Comment: @hoc_age: I supported a previous Latin proposal, but it never took off, there were too few people who were interested...

Comment: Here is a comment on the term by Lord Justice Cozens-Hardy in _Crickitt v. Crickitt_, in _The Law Journal Reports for the Year 1902_: "In 3 _Burn's Ecclesiastical Law_ (9th Ed.), p. 186, this is quoted: 'Tertius intervenire potest pro interesse suo in omni causa quæ tangit bona aut personam suam'; and although interveners were not known to the common law, in the Court of Chancery there were well-known proceedings _pro interesse suo_, which, I apprehend, were simply adopted from the civil law as a peculiar class of cases." A Google Books search finds dozens of matches for _pro interesse suo_.

Comment: @Cerberus There are 50,000 Google results for "pro interesse suo" ... but 22,000 results for "pro suo interesse" which might make more sense ("for oneself to intervene")

Comment: @SvenYargs: That is lamentable...if only the Lord Justice had chosen to employ proper Latin!

Comment: @ChrisW: Mmm not really, one can only intervene *pro se* "for oneself". But it is possible that *suo* agrees with some (elliptical) noun, and that the infinitive is independent of *pro*: then it can work, but it would mean something else.

Answer (score 5):

Pro pretium = for a fee/price.

Pro dictum pretium = for the stated fee/price.

Per pretium = by price/fee.

Comment: The [ablative](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pretium) is "pretio". With "pro" [use the ablative](http://ancienthistory.about.com/od/prepositions/qt/PrepositionsAbl.htm).

Answer (score 4):

Common terms used to indicate that the assistance is not *gratis* are

> - *paid* services
> - *for-fee* services
> - *fee-for-service*

The last, *fee-for-service*, is also used to distinguish a piecemeal payment system from one that is based on a broader representation, such ass retainer services or commission services. *Wikipedia* has a discussion of that issue [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fee-for-service).

Comment: What about "for pay"? I remember having heard that.

Answer (score 3):

Well, the opposite of "for the public good" would be "for profit", which would directly translate into Latin as *pro prodest*.  However, this phrase is not in common English usage and therefore does not carry the same idiomatic weight as *pro bono*.

Comment: Wouldn't the opposite of "for the public good" be "for the public harm"?

Comment: Opposite in this context takes into account the colloquial meaning of "pro bono", which is "for free"

Answer (score 2):

Can't help you with the Latin but in respect of your second point, describing in literal English the term that describes "the arrangement as services being performed at the conventional rate", this is often described as a "Time and Materials" arrangement.

Comment: The term "time and materials" is used in business, but it would never been used by a student speaking to another student about homework help as in the OP's example.